# Odata filter DateTime casting string to DateTime and Filtering

Tags: .net, odata, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to retrieve all records (webinars) after the specific date as follows:

```
var result = await graphClient.Solutions.VirtualEvents.Webinars
.GetByUserIdAndRoleWithUserIdWithRole("organizer", "16b1190f-0552-4c95-90f5-c4d2d852812b").GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Count = true;
    // requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter =
    //     "date(startDateTime/dateTime) ge 2024-03-26T12:00:00Z";
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter =
        "cast(startDateTime/dateTime, Edm.DateTimeOffset) ge 2024-03-26T12:00:00Z";
});
```

The type of the Webinar model StartDateTime.DateTime is a string:
[image]

I've tried different approaches but either I get "Edm.String" and "Edm.DataTimeOffset" error or the filter does not work
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried to filter webinars, but for other endpoints where some property type is `DateTimeTimeZone`, I need to enclose date time in single quotes.

```
$filter=start/dateTime ge '2024-02-03T12:00:00'
```

If you need to include time zone offset, then encode `+` as `%2B`

```
$filter=start/dateTime ge '2024-02-03T12:00:00%2B2' // +2
$filter=start/dateTime ge '2024-02-03T12:00:00-2' // -2
```

I'm not sure whether the Graph SDK will automatically encode `+` in filter query.

```
var result = await graphClient.Solutions.VirtualEvents.Webinars
.GetByUserIdAndRoleWithUserIdWithRole("organizer", "16b1190f-0552-4c95-90f5-c4d2d852812b").GetAsync((rc) =>
{
    rc.QueryParameters.Count = true;
    rc.QueryParameters.Filter = "startDateTime/dateTime ge '2024-03-26T12:00:00Z'";
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work and it doesn't throw an exception but doesn't filter anything. not sure if it's because of the webinar graph API or some other issue

Comment: @ShaneKm If the filter is ignored then the endpoint probably doesn't support filtering by startDateTime.

Comment: trying orderby
rc.QueryParameters.Orderby = new string []{ "displayName" };

doesn't work too i get this message: "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Query option 'OrderBy' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings."

Comment: @ShaneKm The message **The query specified in the URI is not valid. Query option 'OrderBy' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings."** means that it's really not supported on the server side. Unfortunately, it's quite common that the documentation is missing details about properties that support filtering, ordering, etc. :(